# Images loader with Cache?

Tags: android, image, loader

I have to develop a application in which I have to display listview with large listrow.
I want to use a image loader that download image in background and display with smooth and fast scrolling.

Right now I am using these loader link below:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

But scrolling not smooth and fast as I want. Can anybody provide me a link or source code that can solve my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
Google is your friend btw

Comment: @Ascorbin I have used this link. not but useful.

Comment: Use Picasso. https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: @hharry This library does exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: I use Volley, perfect for image loading/caching and other requests as well: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html), and set BitmapFactory.Options to some like:

options. inSampleSize = 10;

Eg:

```
AssetManager asset = MainActivity.this.getAssets();
InputStream istr = asset.open("big_image.jpeg");

BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(istr, false);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 10; // or greater

// here you get the new bitmap with its new size.       
Bitmap bitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(0, 0, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight()), options);
```